# Iptables, enforce multiple rules at the same time

Tags: iptables

I am learning how to use iptables in Ubuntu

there is a server and two clients
my professor asks me to finish the three task below at once:
1.block all accesses from a client except ssh and web access
2.allow at most 2 ssh connections from each client.
3.allow at most 3 total tcp connections from each client.

I can set those rules using 3 command and i think he wants us to use a single command to finish three tasks at once.

I tried:sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 22,80 --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -m connlimit --connlimit-abve 3 -j DROP
But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just ask him what he wants? I don't think it is possible to do so at least based on the fact that you want to introduce both rejecting and accepting rules.

If it is really necessary to do just in one line, you can use `&&` operator between your iptables commands as follows:

`iptables your_rule1 && iptables your_rule2 && iptables your_rule3`

Comment: I will ask him. Thanks anyway!